# Send sms through AT Command acts weird

Tags: delphi, sms, serial-port

I am using ComPort component to send SMS messages via a modem the problem is that sometimes i get sms sometimes not sometimes i get the at commands in the body of the text message.

Here is my code:

```
procedure SendSmsCosmote(numar,text : string);
const
  buf : Byte = 26;
begin
  Form1.ComPort1.WriteStr('AT+CMGF=1'+#13#10);
  Form1.ComPort1.WriteStr('AT+CMGS="'+ numar + '"'+#13);
  Form1.ComPort1.WriteStr(text);
  Form1.ComPort1.Write(buf,1);
end;
```

What am I doing wrong? And why when I read from the modem I get what I sent on the tx line?

Comment: take care about sincron or asincron mode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding slight delay between commands (or wait for modem reply, "OK" usually).

Comment: With delay (how long anyway ?) you cannot be sure the command succeeded, so I would definitely wait for the reply and check its value.

Comment: One second timeout is good. Remember that modems can answer in verbose or numerical mode. Sometimes it is good to establish contact with the modem first by just sending `AT + #13#10`.

Comment: TLama: delay is easy way to test it, and sometimes adequate solution.

Comment: It's still just my own opinion, but from a long time experience; I would never rely on some magic delays, but check the command results wherever it's possible and decide what to do if some of the commands fails. You are the one who controls the module and it can easily happen that the SMS will never be sent. Only sending commands in a row can lead your application to unexpected place in the module's firmware, what is just bad.

Comment: @TLama: If sending message is critical task, then you of course need to take care of whole conversation and handle all exceptions etc. But if it's not critical, adding simple delay is a lot faster way to implement and works probably 99,99% of time.